# Browse files inside a Hyper-V snapshot

Tags: hyper-v, snapshot

If it possible to browse the inside of a snapshot file for a specific file? It is not possible for us to merge this particular snapshot file so we are looking for an alternative to recover a specific file inside it.

How can one open a snapshot file and navigate inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make copies of all the .AVHD and .VHD files associated with your VM in some other location.  Then use Disk Manager to mount the (copy of the) .AVHD file associated with your snapshot.  This requires Server 2008 R2.  The .AVHD files won't show up by default in the user interface, but it can still mount them.

Then browse the file system looking for whatever you like.

Don't try to mount them without copying them, though, or you'll (at best) corrupt your snapshot chain.  Even mounting an NTFS volume changes it.

Comment: Will check that tomorrow once I'm back at work.

Answer (score 3):

Is the snapshot corrupt? If not, why not just take a snapshot of your current environment, and apply the one you want to look at, then re-apply your current one?